# Unable to execute MS-Access Query calling VBA function from C#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, oledb

I am attempting to read a query result from MS Access database programatically.
Code snippet is as follows-

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\\Database1.accdb;"))
{
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new OleDbCommand()
            {
                            CommandText =query,
                            CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                            Connection = connection
            })
            {
                            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader != null)
                                            dataTable.Load(reader);
            }
}
```

The code works fine when we have a simple query like -

**"SELECT column1,column2 FROM tableName"**

But when I try to execute the following query:

**"SELECT func1([column1]),column2 FROM tableName"**

I get an exception -
**"Undefined function 'func1' in expression"**

The function is in a **VBA** module.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can only call functions native to Access this way, not user defined functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any workaround to achieve this that you can suggest ? It's really a critical requirement for us. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Either automate Access from C# (requires Access (runtime?) installed, or replicate the function in C# and replace the SQL with LINQ or DataTables.